# csh up arrow for previous matching command

Tags: csh

How can i configure .cshrc file to use Shift+UpArrow go through history backward search? Also, how can i configure searching cmds with same prefix?
I have tried looking through .cshrc file but doesn't know what to update.

Comment: By "searching", do you mean just that, without executing the command?

Comment: Does `bindkey "^[[1;2A" history-search-backward` do what you want?